# Socket Programming: TCP daytime server?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to implement a simple TCP daytime server

Here is the code that I have written:-

Server code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t clock;
    char buf[256];
    int server_sockfd,client_sockfd;
    int server_len;
    socklen_t client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in servadd;
    struct sockaddr_in cliadd;
    int result;
    fd_set readfds,testfds;
    server_sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    servadd.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servadd.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servadd.sin_port=htons(10205);
    server_len=sizeof(servadd);
    bind(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servadd,server_len);
    listen(server_sockfd,5);
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(server_sockfd,&readfds);
    while(1)
    {
        char ch;
        int fd,nread;
        testfds=readfds;
        printf("\n SERVER WAITING \n");
        result=select(FD_SETSIZE,&testfds,(fd_set *)0,(fd_set *)0,(struct timeval *)0);
        if(result<1)
        {
            perror("Server error");
            exit(1);
        }
        for(fd=0;fd<FD_SETSIZE;fd++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(fd,&testfds))
            {
                if(fd==server_sockfd)
                {
                    client_len=sizeof(cliadd);
                    client_sockfd=accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliadd,&client_len);
                    FD_SET(client_sockfd,&readfds);
                    printf("\n Adding client on fd %d \n",client_sockfd);
                }
                else
                {
                        clock=time(NULL);
                        sleep(5);
                        printf("\n Serving client on fd %d \n",fd);
                        snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"%.24s\r\n",ctime(&clock));

                        //ch++;
                        write(fd,buf,strlen(buf));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Client code:-

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int createsocket=0,n=0;
    char pacr[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in ipos;
    memset(pacr,'0',sizeof(pacr));
    if((createsocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket not created \n");
        //return 1;
    }
    ipos.sin_family=AF_INET;
    ipos.sin_port=htons(10205);
    ipos.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if(connect(createsocket,(struct sockaddr *)&ipos,sizeof(ipos))<0)
    {   
        printf("\n Connection failed \n");
    }
    while((n=read(createsocket,pacr,sizeof(pacr)-1))>0)
    {
        pacr[n]=0;
        if(fputs(pacr,stdout)==EOF)
        {
            printf("\n Standard output error \n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(n<0)
    {
        printf("Standard inp error\n");
    }
//  return 0;
}
```

I am not getting the required output on the client side. It's not printing anything. How can I fix this?

The date and time should be printed on the client side and the server should be able to handle multiple clients.

Comment: why did you use FD_SET etc.? I did never see them before.

Comment: Why are you not checking returns of your calls?

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  Which results in 3 warnings for the 'server' code.  Warnings that you need to fix

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n Socket not created \n");
        //return 1;`  1) when the creation of a socket fails, should exit the program, not keep running as if everything is OK.  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using `perror()` as that will output your message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT: this: `memset(pacr,'0',sizeof(pacr));` can be avoided by using: `char pacr[1024] = { '\0' };`

Comment: regarding the setting of 3 of the fields in `ipos`,  The struct can contain other fields, so it is customary to set the whole struct tp '\0' (via memset()) before setting the individual fields

Comment: the function: `read()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: strongly suggest removing all the code related to the `select()`,  the `readfds`, etc.  The program is listening to the port, so all that is needed is the call to `accept()`  However, always check for error indications from C library functions

Comment: don't go sleeping for 5 seconds after a client connects to the server (the client 'probably' will timeout and disconnect during that 5 second wait)

Comment: there is no provision (nor any real need) for multiple clients to be connected at the same time,  Suggest removing all the code related to handling multiple clients at the same time

Comment: suggest not printing to `stdout` while in the `while()` loop to handle clients.  The printing takes WAY too long

Comment: the sending of the information to the client is using the variable `fd`, BUT the actual client is connected via `client_sockfd`  So nothing will be sent to the client!  Probably the root of the problem

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  2) insert appropriate space: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, inside braces, around C operators

Comment: after writing the 'time' information to the client, should have: `close( client_sockfd );`

Comment: regarding: `int server_len;`  this should be: `socklen_t server_len;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `fwrite`, `write` doesn't guarantee writing all of what you pass.  So one issue you might be facing is that your `write` call on the server simply doesn't write anything to the socket on the first attempt (e.g., returns 0).

Particularly since you're not using a write set with `select`.  You have no idea whether your client socket is ready to accept a write.

To solve this, you may need to keep a structure for each client you are presently serving.  This structure could be something like

`struct _active_connection
{
    char to_send[1024];
    size_t amt_sent;
} my_connections[FD_SETSIZE];`

Then, upon accepting a connection, you'd `FD_SET` the new socket's descriptor into a `writefds` `fd_set` structure that you can check in the same loop that iterates over all of FD_SETSIZE.
That way you can keep your present design that scans all of FD_SETSIZE, but still keeps track of the data pending for any given client---only attempting to continue the writes for client sockets that are ready to accept additional data.

Same general comment on `read` on the client side.  It is perfectly legal for this to return 0, particularly since you're not doing `select` on the client side to determine if the socket has anything waiting to be read.  (And especially considering the `sleep(5)` in the server).  Whether or not you use `select` on the client side, you need to iterate on your `read` until the socket closes (which IIRC,  shows as an error return-code from `read`).  And this means you *also need to close the socket on the server once you're done writing!* lest you just hang until one times-out.

So you might very well be seeing that your client-side `read` returns immediately having read 0 bytes, then the client exits (while the server is still in its `sleep(5)`.  (Your checks on the value returned from `read` exactly miss the case where it returns 0.)